# How to make Firefox extension auto install in nav bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm working on a Firefox extension. I'd like to make it auto-install in the far right position on the nav bar when a user installs it. As it stands, a user has to go to View > Toolbars > Customize... and drag the extension to the nav bar once it's installed. I'd like to eliminate this step.

The extension is here: http://madan.org/tickertool

The XUL for my extension looks basically like this and it overlays browser.xul:

```
<overlay id="my-ext-overlay" ... >
    <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
        <toolbaritem id="my-ext-container" ... >
            <toolbarbutton id="my-ext-customize-image" ... />
            <textbox id="my-ext-textbox" ... />
            <hbox id="my-ext-buttons">
                <image id="my-ext-button1" ... />
                <image id="my-ext-button2" ... />
                <image id="my-ext-button3" ... />
            </hbox>
        </toolbaritem>
    </toolbarpalette>
</overlay>
```

I've seen code here ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Toolbar ) that supposedly does what I'm looking for, but this code is if your extension is just a single button and I can't get it to work for me. The answer to my question is likely some modification of this code, but I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it. It's basically spelled out in the link I mentioned in the original post. I'm not sure why I thought there was more to it than that.